# Is there a way to force OS X / Finder to use Windows File naming conventions?

Tags: macos, finder, windows

We have a number of Mac workstations (OS X Mavericks) which connect to a fiber attached SAN.  This SAN is also accessed by a number of Windows workstations.

Windows file naming conventions (and path depth rules) are stricter than OS X's.  This means the Macs can cause problems for the Windows workstations if they name files or folders in ways which Windows doesn't understand.

As such, is there a way to enforce Windows file naming conventions on OS X?  Thus preventing the Mac clients from screwing up the Windows ones.  I'm thinking some kind of Finder plugin or script that prevents users from naming a file or folder in a way which Windows can't cope with.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you give us an example or two of the types of file names that cause problems?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure such a plugin exists, but [A Better Finder Rename](http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/) is a very powerful app which, in addition to a million and one ways to rename files, has a function to translate OS X filenames for Windows NTFS/SMB compatibility:

[image]

I used it a few years ago to process ~35,000 PDF files made on a Mac, but which needed to be stored on a SMB server. Worked like a charm, and it is FAST!